Ubuntu 24.04 on MSI gs65 stealth 8gs second monitor not recognized
I've recently upgraded to ubuntu 24.04. When connecting the second monitor via HDMI, the monitor is not recognized. Nvidia drivers were purged and reinstalled (550). After reboot, second monitor was recognized. Then went on and powered off the laptop and powered it on again. Now second the monitor is not recognized. Same thing when recovering from suspension.
However, when using an HDMI to DP adapter, there are no issues.
Any ideas what may be going wrong?
kernel: 6.8.0-45-generic
nvidia driver Version: 550.107.02
CUDA Version: 12.4
